# Declaration issues - C++

Tags: c++, gsl

TL;DR - Have some instructions on how to use some C++ code from a github readme (see below) and I'm struggling to implement them as I have never done any C++ before.

So first things first; I am a science student with an okay background in python. I need to use some code thats been written in C++ (I have never used C++ before). Over the past few days I've been googling like a madman in order to figure out how to use the code. Nonetheless excuse me if I've made silly pythonic mistakes everywhere. The github gives these instructions:

"To generate an adjacency matrix for a single statistically homogeneous network in a C++ program, include the header file secorder_rec_1p.hpp and call secorder_rec_1p as

```
    gsl_matrix *W = secorder_rec_1p(N_nodes, p, alpha_recip, alpha_conv,alpha_div, cc_chain, rng);
```

where N_nodes is the number of nodes in the network and rng is a pointer to an initialized gsl random number generator. W is an adjacency matrix where W_ij=1 if there is a connection from node j onto node i and is zero otherwise."

For someone who has never done C++ before this was at first rather confusing. After much googling etc it is now less confusing and I have a .c file that I was hoping would do the trick. Unfortunately it's giving me an error I somewhat understand but dont know how to fix.

so my code is:

```
    #include "secorder_rec_1p.hpp"
    #include <time.h>
    #include <gsl/gsl_rng.h>
    using namespace std;

    extern int N;
    extern double p, recip, conv, divg, chain;

    int main (){
        int N;
        N = 1000;
        gsl_rng * rng = gsl_rng_alloc(gsl_rng_taus); //I'm not really sure what it does but I don't get any mention of this in the errors so I think it's ok. Not entirely sure if this is a "pointer to an initialized gsl random num generator"


        double p, recip, conv, divg, chain;
        recip = 0.1;
        p = 0.1;
        conv = 0.1;
        divg = 0.1;
        chain = 0.1;

        int W [N][N];
        int i,j;
        double result = rand()/ RAND_MAX;
        for(i=0; i<N; i++)
            for(j=0; j<N; j++)
            {
                if(result > p){
                    W [i][j] = 1;
                } else {
                    W[i][j] = 0;
                }

            }

        gsl_matrix *W = secorder_rec_1p(N, p, recip, conv, divg, chain, rng);
    }
```

I'm getting a declaration error when I try to "make" the .c file (this is compiling it right? I need to do this before I can actually run the script?). The error cites a conflicting declaration with my W's.

My (obviously incorrect) understanding is that I'm creating an N by N array (matrix?) that is filled with 1s and 0s where element M_ij is 1 with a probability p and 0 otherwise.

Then this is where my understanding falls apart a little, but *W means it points to the thing labelled by W, so it should be my matrix and a gsl_matrix that are equal to the output of that function. I'm not sure what the equals means in this case because it should be generating a new matrix. So if this was python I'd expect the name of my new matrix to be on the left hand side of the equals and the stuff on the right the code used to generate it. I'm not sure what's going on here though.

Any help with my error as well as information about how c++ works etc is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have two different variables named `W`. `int W [N][N];` and `gsl_matrix *W` - that doesn't work

Comment: So did the author of the code from github mean something different in their readme?

Comment: `I have a .c file that I was hoping would do the trick.` should not it be `a .cpp`?

Comment: I don't know the difference yet, and tutorials I found on writing c++ always said .c but I had been wondering if it made a difference

Comment: File endings are just a convention, though some compilers use them as hints to decide whether to compile files as C or C++. Also you should post the exact error messages you get instead of transcribing them (e.g.: `gsl_rng * rng =` looks very suspicious)

Comment: `int W [N][N];` where `N` is a variable is invalid in C++.    If your compiler accepts such a thing, it is a non-standard compiler extension.    Beyond that, you need to spend some time learning C++ before you try to use someone else's code.   Otherwise, you will just be guessing, and get in trouble.   And anyone trying to help you will probably give explanations that are completely correct but incomprehensible to you.

Comment: If you make `N` a `constexpr` variable, it should work though.

Comment: C++ is a complex language, going by some Readme and attempting to port Python to it I don't think will work to well. Better to go with some C++ tutorial or book to cover static typing, declarations, pointers, memory management, etc. as very different from Python.

Comment: Yes I just thought since the github code was already finished and working it would be trivial to learn to write a script that just calls the function and saves the output somehow (mainly because its only a couple of lines in python)

Comment: @bidby you are a student right? Best thing for you in my opinion is to ask help from a colleague or even from an assistant.

Comment: sadly none of my colleagues know c++, and my supervising professor is away at a conference

Comment: do you understand that you declare `W` twice (and with different types) and that's illegal in C++? The simple fix is to rename one of the `W` to something else. E.g. `gsl_matrix *X = ...`